# easiest way to scale div to 100% of parent's div with other div on same level?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

so here's an outside flex div with two childs, what is the easiest way to center content inside child1 by parent width, not by itself, without using  padding's or margin's

```html
<div title='parent' style='display: flex; width: 200px'>
  <div title='child1' style='border:1px solid black; width: 100%; text-align: center'>
long
  </div>
  <div title='child2' style='border:1px solid red; width: 40px'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`text-indent` can do the job here but use `flex-grow:1` instead of `width:100%` to avoid shrinking the second element

```html
<div title='parent' style='display: flex; width: 200px'>
  <div title='child1' style='border:1px solid black; flex-grow:1; text-align: center;text-indent:40px'>
long
  </div>
  <div title='child2' style='border:1px solid red; width: 40px'>
  </div>
</div>
```